# Как работать с числом, введенным пользователем, не вызывая ввод снова

Tags: java, scanner

Допустим, что есть
int vvod = scanner.nextInt();
как я могу теперь работать с введенным числом? Сравнивать с ним другие числа и тп. Мне нужна проверка на целое число, но без try-catch. Иначе, если я ввожу не число, idea даёт ошибку. Если я реализую проверку has.NextInt() то как мне потом его использовать для сравнения с др числами?
 Прошу вашей помощи. Заранее спасибо.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Monthes {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Введи количество дней от 1 до 31");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            if (sc.nextInt() == 28 || sc.nextInt() == 30 || sc.nextInt() == 31) {
                switch (sc.nextInt()) {
                    case 28:
                        System.out.println("Февраль");
                    case 30:
                        System.out.println("апрель\nиюнь\nсентябрь\nноябрь");
                    case 31:
                        System.out.println("январь\nмарт\nмай\nиюль\nавгуст\nоктябрь\nдекабрь");
                }
            } else {
                if (sc.nextInt() < 28) {
                    System.out.println("Столько дней содержитя в каждом месяце");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Введите кол-во дней от 1 до 31");
                }
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто сперва проверяете целое ли это число: `if (scanner.hasNextInt() { ... // а тут уже создаете переменную int n = scanner.nextInt(); к примеру }`. И просто дальше работаете с переменной `n` (потому что каждый вызов сканера ожидает ввода числа, а Вы хотите вводить только один раз)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень Вам благодарен за помощь @entithat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int vvod = 0;
while(true){
    String strValue = scanner.nextLine();
    if (!strValue.matches("-?\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Вы ввели не число, введите еще раз");
        continue;
    } else {
        vvod = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
        break;
    }
}
//теперь делаем с переменной vvod, что захотим
```

Без `try-catch`, как Вы и просили.